# Need to create a user application in python-Django framework where based on input data will insert or update in the database

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am a newbie in python-Django and i have a requirement where i need to create  a template where there will be a text input name (id) and a drop down as OPS(view,insert,edit) and by giving the id and selecting view as ..it will check into the db and will show all the project details in the template.

For view:it will display all the records in the table.

For Insert:It will insert the records in the table based on the input parameters passed in the form.

For update:It will show all the fields and a user can edit and save it which will update the database from backend.

I wanted to know how to create a model which will link the existing database with that of this django for the table.So it can update and insert records through template.

Please help me on this

Comment: Could you be more specific with the records that you want to show? I mean do you know what tables and records will it have?

Comment: What about doing things in the right order : 1. learn Python (the official tutorial should be enough), 2. learn Django (at least the official tutorial) and 3. work on your actual project.

Comment: Actually i am a bit confused about models..I mean how to map the database with Django through models..If i hit the insert button in template how it will insert  the record into the database....i m not getting the flow..

Answer (score 1):

check out the official [example (models)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/#creating-models)

models in the django orm look like this

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    foo = models.IntegerField()  # a field in the model
```

You will need to read the official documentation or check out other django applications.